# Migration from VS2005 to VS2013 for native c++ code is causing error during execution

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, dev-c++

I have migrated my ACTIVEX code from vs2005 to vs2013. My exe is using the below MS files in deploy directory.
ATL80.dll
Microsoft.VC80.ATL.manifest
Microsoft.VC80.CRT.manifest

In VS2013 I am not seeing this files. However Microsoft says that ATL80.dll is not supported in VS2013. They have added those information in header files and static libraries.
 Can some one give me information about the equivalent files in Vs2013 for the above mentioned files. When I run my exe it gives error the file MicrosoftVC80.ATL.manifest is needed.

Comment: Those are VS2005 runtime support files.  Still having a dependency on them after rebuilding in VS2013 is very, very, very unhealthy.  Even if you properly install them, your next problem will typically be a nasty memory leak or heap corruption issue, caused by having more than one copy of the CRT in your process.  You did not rebuild all of the code, usually a static library is easy to miss.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for reply can you help me knowing the equivalent manifest file in VS2013. Secondly ATL80.dll equivalent  is not supported in vs2013. How can we use atl dlls functionality in 2013.

Comment: VS2013 no longer uses a manifest.  ATL is alive and well, you simply won't have a dependency on a DLL anymore when you rebuild your project correctly.  Only thing you have to take care of is rebuilding *all* the code.  Use the linker's /verbose option if you have no idea what libraries are getting linked.

Comment: [ATL and MFC changes and fixes in Visual Studio 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/08/20/atl-and-mfc-changes-and-fixes-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx) explains what Hans Passant said in a bit more detail.